# Parse Xcode 8 and swift 3 CompletianHandler error

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, swift3, xcode8

I updated to xcode 8 and my code was updated to swift 3. Now i get errors wherever i used blocks inside my code with Parse. Here is one example

`query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?)`'

Here's the error:

```
cannot convert value of type '([PFObject]?, NSError?) ->() to expected argument type '([PFObject]?, Error?) -> Void?'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?)' in`

Comment: do you happen to know if Parse Server or Parse.com supports IPv6? My app was rejected when Parse returned and error while "using IPv6 wifi"?

Comment: You don't need to use IPv6 you just need to function properly on an IPv6 only network. Lots of info here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/719/ and here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1